# Time Capsule external connections

Tags: time-capsule

**I recently purchased a new 2TB Time Capsule. Can I connect my old Time Capsule to it to serve as an external drive?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the New as main router and create a WiFi network. Then have the Old join in (as an Access Point in jargon). It's the same is accessing a shared disk on another Mac laptop/desktop.

Or you can link them with Ethernet cable.